# Wait for callback to complete in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

Currently writing a flutter app using the [flutter_tts](https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts) library.

I have a list of sentences to read out, but currently having trouble waiting for the **setCompletionHandler()** to complete.

How can I wait for the **setCompletionHandler()** callback to complete before moving on to the next string? Currently, the **TTS.speak()** function finishes immediately with the while loop incrementing right away so it only reads out the last sentence in the list.

```dart
// code shortened for brevity

FlutterTts TTS;
TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;

get isPlaying => ttsState == TtsState.playing;
get isStopped => ttsState == TtsState.stopped;

List<String> sentences = ['Hello, World', 'How are you?', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'];

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    TTS = FlutterTts();
}

void readOutSentences(sentences) async {
    int i = 0;
    bool readCompleted = false;

    while (i < sentences.length) {
        readCompleted = await runSpeak(sentences[i].toString());

        if (readCompleted)
          i++;
    }
}

Future<bool> runSpeak(String currentSentence) async {
    TTS.setStartHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        ttsState = TtsState.playing;
      });
    });

    TTS.setCompletionHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });

    await TTS.speak(currentSentence);

    return true;
}

readOutSentences(sentences);
```

Comment: Which function do you want to wait for?

Comment: **TTS.setCompletionHandler()** runs after **TTS.speak()** is completed. Need to wait/listen to the **TTS.setCompletionHandler()** function before incrementing the while loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you declare the completion and start handlers outside of **runSpeak** and just calling them inside that function? I think that because you just declare the completion and start handlers in the function, Dart just calls TTS.speak(currentSentence) because the other two are just declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive about the setCompletionHandler)

You can use such async functions:

```
  Future<void> _speak(String _text) async {
    if (_text != null && _text.isNotEmpty) {
      await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
      await flutterTts.speak(_text);
    }
  }

  readAllSentencesList(List<String> allSentences) async {
    for (int i=0; i<allSentences.length; i++){
      await _speak(allSentences[i]);
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to use last flutter_tts library!

Answer (score 0):

Set `setCompletionHandler` like following to speak all sentences of the list one by one.

```
List<String> sentences = ['Hello, World', 'How are you?', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog']

int i = 0;

FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();

await flutterTts.speak(sentences[i]);

flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() async {
  if (i < sentences.length - 1) {
    i++;
    await flutterTts.speak(sentences[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the callback use the await keyword:

```
await TTS.setCompletionHandler(() {
  setState(() {
    ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
  });
});
```